# Webflux RSocket Server using RSocketRequestor sending message to Rsocket-js client .Responder not receiving

Tags: spring-boot, webflux, rsocket-js

My requirement is that as and when some event happens on server, it should push updates to client. Want to use RSocket and not SSE.
Will responder configured on the rsocket-js client respond to server request?
If yes then how should the rsocket-js responder be configured to accept message on a particular route? That part please clarify.
Not sure if my spring service is correct.

My Webflux Spring Boot RSocket server code-

```java
@Service  
@RequiredArgsConstructor  
public class RsocketService {  
    private final RSocketRequester rSocketRequester;  

    public void serverToClientRequest(){  

        Mono.just("Your request  is completed at "+ LocalDateTime.now())
           .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(5, 10)))   
           .flatMap(m -> rSocketRequester.route("request.stream").data(m).send())  
           .subscribe();
    }  
}
```

I have a Controller -

```java
@MessageMapping("request.stream")  
public Flux<String> requestStream(@Payload String requestData) {  
}
```

Client side I am using  RSocketWebSocketClient from 'rsocket-websocket-client';

```
const client = new RSocketClient({   
  responder: new EchoResponder(),  
  transport: new RSocketWebSocketClient(  
    {
      url: 'ws://localhost:7000/rsocket',  
      wsCreator: (url: string) => new WebSocket(url),  
      debug: true,  
    }
  ),  
  setup: {  
    dataMimeType: "text/plain",
    metadataMimeType: 'message/x.rsocket.routing.v0',
    keepAlive: 600000,
    lifetime: 180000,
  }
});
```

My reactjs component-

```
async componentDidMount() {  
    const rsocket= await client.connect();  
    console.log('rsocket client connected');  
     rsocket
            .requestStream({
              data: "client message",
              metadata: String.fromCharCode('request.stream'.length) + 'request.stream'
            })
            .subscribe({
              onComplete: () => {
                console.log("request stream completed");

              },
              onNext: value => {
                console.log("on next-->got data from sever");
                console.log(value.data);
              },
              onError: (error: any) => {
                console.log("got error with requestResponse");
                console.error(error);
              },
              onSubscribe: sub => {
                console.log("subscribe request Stream!");
                sub.request(2147483647);
              }
            });
        }
```

EchoResponder is taken from https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-js/blob/master/packages/rsocket-examples/src/LeaseClientExample.js. But the responder does not get any message. Any help is appreciated please.